# Keyboard layout edge cropping up while running the app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, android-softkeyboard, android-relativelayout

[image]

This is a layout i created using **dp** dimensions using a relative layout for keyboard, But when i try the keyboard on my phone, somehow, the right edge of my keyboard gets cropped as shown below, what could be the reason for this problem?

[image]

Here's my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/Rel">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/texty"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/xcor"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/ycor"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonh"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttono1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="अ"
        android:id="@+id/अ"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonh"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttono1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="आ"
        android:id="@+id/आ"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text"/>
    ....

    Lots of Buttons


   .....
    <Button
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttono5"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#FF494949"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/buttono5"
        android:text="."
        android:id="@+id/dot"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#FF494949"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="330dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:src="@drawable/enterbutton"
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:textSize="17dp"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

As suggested in comments.

I tried changing width of my parent to some constant dp instead of **match_parent** but the result is same.

**EDIT**
I found out this bug only occurs on my phone which is an Oreo, Xiaomi Redmi note 5.

Comment: try to make your width as 0dp and set constraint for right and left 0dp with respect to parent layout

Comment: Width of each button?

Comment: width of the layout in which all the buttons are placed. It will be great if you place your xml code here

Comment: Here, i added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your can use  `layout_weight`

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

its responsive over display

Comment: I tried that, it works, although i don't exactly understand why...what do you mean it's responsive over display?